# How do I extract parts of a string to variables?

Tags: bash, regular-expression, string

I have a line from some file like this:

```
attempting to create a 512^3 level (with Dirichlet BC) using a 16^3 grid of 32^3 boxes and 800 tasks...
```

I want to extract the `512^3`, `16^3`, `32^3` and `800` four numbers from it and assign them respectively to four variables `level`, `grid`, `boxes` and `tasks` for other use.

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes, the first three of them has the format a^b and last one just usual number.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Bash can match regular expressions with the `=~` operator in `[[ ... ]]`:

```
#! /bin/bash

line='attempting to create a 512^3 level (with Dirichlet BC) using a 16^3 grid of 32^3 boxes and 800 tasks...'
num='([0-9^]+)'
nonum='[^0-9^]+'
if [[ $line =~ $num$nonum$num$nonum$num$nonum$num ]] ; then
    level=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    grid=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
    boxes=${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
    tasks=${BASH_REMATCH[4]}
    echo "Level $level, grid $grid, boxes $boxes, tasks $tasks."
fi
```

Comment: Wow, never knew Bash could do something like this :)

Comment: FYI 1: when writing the regexp directly, **do not put it in quotes**. For example `[[ 
'Example 123' =~ '([0-9]+)' ]]` is false, but `[[ 
'Example 123' =~ ([0-9]+) ]]` works as intended.

Comment: FYI 2: capture does **not** work multiple times. For example `[[ '1_2_3' =~ ([0-9]) ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[@]}` only matches `1`.

Answer (score 2):

If this is output from a program / script you've written and the text is formulaic (i.e. follows this pattern exactly) you can just use `cut`.

```
#!/bin/bash

$STRING='attempting to create a 512^3 level (with Dirichlet BC) using a 16^3 grid of 32^3 boxes and 800 tasks...'

level=$(echo $STRING | cut -d' ' -f5 -)
grid=$(echo $STRING | cut -d' ' -f12 -)
boxes=$(echo $STRING | cut -d' ' -f15 -)
tasks=$(echo $STRING | cut -d' ' -f18 -)
```

Answer (score 2):

Using awk:

```
awk '{print "level="$5"\n""grid="$12"\n""boxes="$15"\n""tasks="$18}' file     
level=512^3
grid=16^3
boxes=32^3
tasks=800
```

Answer (score 1):

If the line always has exactly this structure, [`read`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-read) can do this in a single line with no external processes:

```
read x x x x level x x x x x x grid x x boxes x x tasks x <<<"$line"
```

(also using a [herestring](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)). This will save all the words you don't care about into `x` (to be ignored) and the values you wanted into their respective variables.